# Drupal: View with exposed Taxonomy filter.. 2 questions

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I'm using Views module and an exposed taxonomy based filter, to allow users to select a subselection of articles.

I need to further customize my filter:

1. I want the user able to order the tags alphabetically by clicking a checkbox (if this checkbox is unchecked the default order is reset.
2. I want all tags selected in the beginning to show my user all the articles. (Additional tags can be added by the user later, so I cannot just select all the tags in Views settings, because the new ones would be uncovered).

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) jquery script that adds check-box (or link as text or pic) and if it is checked, rearranges menu or list
2) rephrase question, i have no whiskey at home

Answer (score 0):

what about the other way round?? -> selected tag means "show".

how do your filters work?? You don't use http://drupal.org/project/faceted_search ?

i am starting with it and like it.

Comment: I'm inspecting faceted_search. Are you sure it provides the functionalities I asked before ? About "the other way round": at the moment selected tag means "show". However I would like when I visit the webpage for the first time, none of them is selected and all articles are visible.

Comment: I think faceted_search doesn't solve my problem.. I'm going to inspect the php code, because I don't see any module available.